# Detect "Improve Location Accuracy" on/off state on Android 11 (API 30)

Tags: android, location

I need to check that the "Improve Location Accuracy" is turned on or off by the user. Until now I checked via `NETWORK_PROVIDER`

```
    val locationManager = (getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager)
    val network = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
```

and the result was false on Android 10 and below when option turned off (and true when on), but on Android 11 the result is true, however is off.

I tried `LocationServices.checkLocationSettings` and `failureListener` called if turned off, so it can be ok, but it's async.

This is my test video:

https://youtu.be/EmCyvv5tfr4

Answer (score 1):

It was emulator bug, recreate it solved the problem